# Understanding Logging Example in Parallel and Concurrent Haskell

Tags: haskell

In the MVar Logging Example from [Parallel and Concurrent Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch07.html#sec_conc-logger), it shows the following:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

data Logger = Logger (MVar LogCommand)

data LogCommand = Message String | Stop (MVar ())

initLogger :: IO Logger
initLogger = do
  m <- newEmptyMVar
  let l = Logger m
  forkIO (logger l)
  return l

logger :: Logger -> IO ()
logger (Logger m) = loop
  where 
   loop = do
    cmd <- takeMVar m
    case cmd of 
      Message msg -> putStrLn msg >> loop
      Stop s -> do
        putStrLn "logger: stop"
        putMVar s ()

logMessage :: Logger -> String -> IO ()
logMessage (Logger m) s = putMVar m (Message s)

logStop :: Logger -> IO ()
logStop (Logger m) = do
  s <- newEmptyMVar
  putMVar m (Stop s)
  takeMVar s
```

What would be lost if `logger`'s last line, namely `putMVar s ()`, were deleted?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: No. Thank you for calling me out on it. I should have and then asked a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `putMVar s ()`, calling `logStop` would hang in `takeMVar s` because nothing else can fill `s`. Eventually a [`BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar) exception would be thrown, killing the hung thread.

`s` exists for orderly shutdown. It guarantees that by the time `logStop` returns, the log processing thread has actually stopped.

See also this text from the page you linked:

> [...] `logStop` causes the logging service to terminate. The latter operation is important because if we want to shut down the program, we need to be sure that the logging service has finished processing any outstanding requests. Recall from [“A Simple Example: Reminders”](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch07.html#sec_reminders) that when the main thread exits, the program terminates immediately rather than waiting for other threads to terminate first. Hence `logStop` has an extra requirement: it must not return until the logging service has processed all outstanding requests and stopped.

[...]

> After sending the command, we call `takeMVar` on the new `MVar` to wait for the response. After the logging thread has processed the `Stop` command, it puts `()` into this `MVar`, which allows the `takeMVar` to continue and `logStop` to return.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be reasonable, then, to remove the `takeMVar s` in `logStop`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith ... Did you read the first paragraph I quoted?